# Is it possible to animate complications with WatchKit/ClockKit?

Tags: ios, clockkit

Obviously WatchOS is a resource constrained environment, and it's clear executed applications can animate to their heart's content, but is it possible for an active complication (specifically the large Modular center) to receive a context that can display frames over small numbers of milliseconds -- a moving graph, or even just changing text?  Or is that functionality Apple has not exposed?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for `getTimelineEntries(for complication` states:

> Entries must be greater than one minute apart.

So it seems the finest granularity you can have in Complications is >60s.